# txt file write works in emulator but not in real device xcode

Tags: xcode, file-io

Hi all We wrote a program that works pretty fine on emulator. But when we upload project to our own device it can read the file and display items but when it tries to erase file and write again it doesnt work.

What might be the possible problems and how to fix this issue?

Comment: can you write code please

Comment: [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath: filePath error: nil];
     [[NSData data] writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
      NSFileHandle *handle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:filePath];
     [handle truncateFileAtOffset:[handle seekToEndOfFile]];
     [handle writeData:[something dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

Comment: try to use `NSString *directory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];` as directory. Then full path is so: `directory = [directory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];`

Comment: Don't post all of your code in comments. Update your question with the code so people can read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you are trying to write the file in the app bundle. For security purposes, Apple does not let you touch the bundle. You have to :

- Check that your file exists in the sandbox
- If not, copy it from the app bundle
- Then, work with the copied file

I think it works in the simulator because there is no sandbox when you run your app in the simulator.
The documentation for finding the right folders in your app's sandbox is below.

[Sandbox documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/TheiOSEnvironment/TheiOSEnvironment.html)

[File System programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html)

EDIT :

Here is some code (did not run it in Xcode, there could be some typo errors) to copy a file from bundle into a given directory in the Documents directory. Be careful this code overrides the file in the Documents directory every time.

```
NSString *documentsDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
NSString *fileDirectory = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyDirectory"];

// Create folder if it does not exist
BOOL isDirectory;
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:fileDirectory isDirectory:&isDirectory])
{
    NSError *error;
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:fileDirectory withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];
    if(error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error creating folder : %@",error.localizedDescription);
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Folder created");
    }
}

// Save to disk
NSString *filePathOnDisk = [fileDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"fileInSandbox.foo"];
NSString *pathFromBundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"fileFromBundle" ofType:@"foo"];
NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pathFromBundle];
NSError *error;
if (![fileData writeToFile:filePathOnDisk options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error])
{
    NSLog(@"Error writing file : %@", error.localizedDescription);
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"File saved to disk successfully");
}
```

Then, when you want to work with your copied file, use the path we created in `filePathOnDisk`.

Once again, please, read the documentation related to file management in order to understand what you're doing with your files.

Comment: the thing is that we have the created file and display.It can read from that file but the problem is it can not write or append in that file .

Comment: That's exactly why you have to copy it in the app' sandbox when your app run for the first time. Then, you'll always work with the copied file in order to edit it.

Comment: how I can do that "copy it from the app bundle
Then, work with the copied file"

Comment: Edited the answer with some code... But don't forget to read the documentation !